# Save output of p-values from stargazer package as object?

Tags: r, linear-regression, stargazer

Hi I want to save the p value computed from stargazer as an object either vector or dataframe. So for example

```
   linear.1 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning 
                            + raises + critical, data=attitude)
    ## put in the p-values rather than the se's
    stargazer(linear.1, type="text", report=('vc*p'))
```

Would be great if I can save the output such as p value, f statistics so that I can use in my downstream analysis?  thanks!

Comment: `stargazer` itself returns only text. There are then two options. First, focus on a single object/function, like `lm`, and extract relevant figures from it instead (e.g., `linear.1`). This should always be possible and easy. Second, be specific about what you want to extract from the `stargazer` table. Then we could use regex for this purpose.

Comment: @JuliusVainora thanks, looks like its only text.  I think the best is to just to calculate this manually.

Answer (score 0):

The information is already in the model object, as the comment suggests.

```
linear.1 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning + raises + critical, data=attitude)

summary(linear.1)$fstatistic # f statistic
   value    numdf    dendf 
12.06311  5.00000 24.00000 

summary(linear.1)$coefficients[,4] # p value
 (Intercept)   complaints   privileges     learning       raises     critical 
0.3561781673 0.0001014085 0.4495905743 0.1317679549 0.8699985577 0.9171040097
```